# Automate editing .csv file

Tags: csv, scripting

I am working with some .CSV files that contain 4 fields and a varying count of records in each file. I need to delete the 2nd, 3rd and 4th field and the first record in each file.

I have a lot of files I am working and not looking to do this in Excel or with a CSV Editor. Is there a way to do this with a batch file or other scripting language ?  Thanks for any info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using shell script:

```
tail -n +2 input.csv | cut -d ',' -f 1,5- > output.csv
```

Comment: thanks for the info.  I should have mentioned I am working in Windows. Is there a method in Windows to do this?   Thanks.

Comment: I found the answer on another site. Here is how to do it in a batch file                                                                  @echo off
(for /F "delims=," %%A in (input.csv) do echo %%A) > output.csv